# Non-blocking Neo4j Scala driver

Tags: scala, neo4j, driver, nonblocking

Is there non-blocking Scala driver for Neo4J. Don't have to be production grade but stable enough and provide support for core Neo4J operations/features.

Comment: What do you mean under the "non-blocking" term? I'm currently playing around with neo4j/scala combination, which I'm going to open as soon as it will be at least 50% ready/stable and I might be interested in implementing your idea, as soon as you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: "non-blocking" in this case means something similar to what other datastore drivers provide. https://github.com/etaty/rediscala, https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo

Comment: Why not use the http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html and thin wrapper using http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-client/#spray-client ?

Comment: Currently I'm using the REST API (with Java) and it works with some know performance issues because of using REST over native calls to the Neo4J database. I'm trying to implement some new interfaces to putting and querying data into new graphs and though I would experiment with doing it in Scala (I'm new to Scala). I've moved my Redis calls from using Jedis (in Java) to Rediscala (in Scala).